# HBox not visible

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-8

I try simple test

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GREEN, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        hBox.setPrefHeight(100);
        hBox.setPrefWidth(100);
        pane.getChildren().add(hBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Expecting see green square HBox on red Pane, but see just red pane.
But if I use HBox directly as root view (passing it to `new Scene()`), green box is visible.

Why HBox is missed inside Pane?

Comment: Did you try adding something to your HBox, soemething like this: Button button1 = new Button("Button Number 1");
        Button button2 = new Button("Button Number 2");

        HBox hbox = new HBox(button1, button2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a `BorderPane` as the root pane, and adding your `HBox` to it using

```
pane.getChildren().add(hBox);
```

`BorderPane` is a layout pane that manages the position and size of its child nodes in a specific way. There are five regions, and the size and position of the child node depends not only on the `min`, `pref`, and `max` sizes of the child, but also on the region to which the child is assigned.

In the case of the code you posted, since you didn't assign a region at all, the `HBox` gets zero size.

If you place the `HBox` in other regions, you will get different (but not necessarily the desired) behavior. If you place the `HBox` in the left or right, the `HBox` will be assigned its preferred width, but its height will be the full height of the border pane. Conversely, if you place it in the top or bottom, it will be assigned its preferred height, but stretch the full width of the border pane. (If you place it in the center, it will stretch the full width and height of the border pane.)

You probably (depending on the exact behavior you are looking for) just want a plain pane here:

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
```